# How can I set the seed that MLFlow uses to randomly generate run names?

Tags: huggingface-transformers, mlflow

I am currently setting the random number generator seed for Hugging Face transformers with `transformers.set_seed()` . I found that function also sets the seed for MLFlow and, as a consequence, I always get the same sequence of run and nested run names from MLFlow, which is to me undesirable.

After setting the Hugging Face transformers seed, I would like to be able to reset the seed for MLFlow to a different value (or a random value).

How can I set the seed that MLFlow uses to randomly generate run names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MLFLow uses python module `random` to randomly generate a run name, see the implementation of `_generate_string()` in `name_utils.py`. Therefore the way to set the seed for that would be to just call `random.seed()`.

The implementation of the transformers `set_seed()` sets a variety of random seeds, including `random.seed()`.

It seems to me that in order to have random run names from MLFlow, either I don't call `set_seed()`, but I manually set the seeds for Numpy and Pytorch, or I call `random.seed()` myself after calling `set_seed()`.